# Barplot Error in R

Tags: r

I recently created a barplot in R using some sample data with no trouble. Then I tried it again using the real data which was exactly the same as the sample data except there was more of it. The problem is now I get this error:

```
Error in barplot.default(table(datafr)) : 
   'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

I don't know if this is of help but when I print out the table these are what the last lines look like.

```
33333  2010-09-13-19:25:50.206                             Google Chrome-#135   NA
  [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 342611 rows ]]
```

Is it possible that this is too much data to process? Any suggestion as to how I can fix this?

Thanks :)

---

**EDIT 1**

Hey Joris,

Here is the info from str(datafr) :

```
'data.frame':   375944 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ TIME     : Factor w/ 375944 levels "2010-09-11-19:28:34.680 ",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ FOCUS.APP: Factor w/ 107 levels " Finder-#101  ",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 ...  
 $ X        : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

and from traceback()

```
3: stop("'height' must be a vector or a matrix")
2: barplot.default(table(datafr))
1: barplot(table(datafr))
```

I also ran the other command you told me, but the feedback was super verbose; too much to print here. Let me know if you need any other info or if the last information was really important I can figure out a way to post it.

Thanks,

Comment: could you add the traceback? (run the code, when you get the error, type traceback() and copy what you see there). Also try to find an example that we can try ourselves. Right now the only thing anyone can say is that apparently your real data is not exactly the same as the sample data, otherwise it would have worked.

Comment: Also do  dput(head(datafr,n=20)) and str(datafr) and put this in your question. That will tell us how the data is structured, and probably why you get this error.

Comment: Try running `str(dataA)` and `str(dataB)` to get at the difference between your working / non--working datasets. The `summary()` function may also help.

Comment: Don't mind the output of dput to be very verbose. SO cuts this to 30 lines and hides the rest. The output allows me to read in the first 20 lines of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, that solves the problem : you have 3 dimensions in your table, barplot can't deal with that. Take the 2 columns you want to use for the barplot function, eg:

```
# sample data
Df <- data.frame(
  TIME = as.factor(seq.Date(as.Date("2010-09-11"),as.Date("2010-09-20"),by="day")),
  FOCUS.APP = as.factor(rep(c("F101","F102"),5)),
  X = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE,NA),10,r=T)
)

# make tables
T1 <- table(Df)
T2 <- table(Df[,-3])

# plot tables
barplot(T1)
barplot(T2)
```

This said, that plot must look interesting to say the least. I don't know what you try to do, but I'd say that you might to reconsider your approach to it.